# Getting a 502 with EBS with Spring Boot running single instance, port already opened

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have a set up where in a spring-boot project.

I've edited the deployment script to upload the JAR file, not the entire source.

When I go into the EBS logs, I can see that my server is running.

I've set up SERVER_PORT, and I can see from the EBS logs that Tomcat is running in port 5000.

Odd thing is, even hitting the EC2 instance's public IP is giving me a 502.

Can you guys help me cross more things off of the check list?

Comment: Have you checked on the server Is service accessible. Are you getting logs on app for 502 error?

Comment: Surprisingly, 502 status does not always come from the server. Sometimes it comes from a proxy (or even some routers) when it's faulty or can't interpret the answer properly. And in your case, I would doubt 502 really comes from spring boot app as embedded tomcat does not act as a gateway in this case (thus 502 is not exactly legitimate). So, yeah, enable access log in your app and see if you can find your requests in the log. I'd also suggest trying from another network (e.g. from home) to rule out misbehaving proxy.

Comment: And I assume we're talking about plain EC2 instance, not Elastic Beanstalk. And that you did not configure nginx or anything like that in front of your web app. Is it correct? Sorry if these are silly questions. Just 502 would be a really weird response from a spring boot app. So, I want to make sure we're not missing something important, which you might have forgotten to mention.

Comment: @Seva this sounds like beanstalk to me.  It's a pretty common (and reasonably understandable) error for new users to assume "EBS" and "Elastic Beanstalk" refer to the same thing, only later to learn that "EBS" is actually [tag:amazon-ebs] and not [tag:amazon-elastic-beanstalk].

Comment: @Seva I didn't configure the EC2 instance, and hitting the EC2 instance directly with port 80 gives me 502. Port 5000 and 8080 times out eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, sounds like Elastic Beanstalk to me. So, below I will assume it is.

> I didn't configure the EC2 instance, and hitting the EC2 instance directly with port 80 gives me 502.

This means you do have nginx (or similar) in front of your server. And it's nginx that is responding with 502, not your app.

> Port 5000 and 8080 times out eventually.

And this is actually the reason for 502 response - nginx tries to pass a request over to your app, but times out and then responds with "502 Bad Gateway".

Elastic Beanstalk runs your app in a docker container inside an EC2 instance. And then uses nginx (running on actual EC2 instance and acting as a reverse proxy) to make your app accessible outside of EC2 instance (e.g. visible to your load balancer). I'm afraid that inner workings of this setup are a bit too complicated to fit into an answer. But cutting long story short, you must first check that 5000 is the correct port that nginx will use to find your app. Beware, it may vary between "Beanstalk Supported Platforms", for example for Go platform it's 3000 (if my memory is correct). Secondly, make sure that this port is exposed in your docker file. And thirdly, make sure that your spring boot app listens on that port.

This seems to be a good short article for your reference: https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/

And well, in the worst case you can always try packaging it as a war instead and using Beanstalk's "Java with Tomcat" platform. It's a bit simpler to use as you won't need to bother about ports.

Comment: I'm dumb. The app was running before, but when I had rebuilt the environment to remove RDS dependency from EBS, it was having trouble booting up.

Comment: I don't think you're dumb. I had spend quite a bit of time learning inner workings of EBS. And I can tell it is configured extremely well. And it worked really well for me while it was just a simple web app. But I myself had stopped using EBS exactly for the reason that any serious changes in configuration (in order to adapt to changing demands and requirements) quickly becomes too complicated. So, did you manage to fix database connectivity? EBS includes own RDS support, but you should be able to connect to an RDS outside of EBS just as easily. It just won't be managed by EBS.